# android - json key value pairs to sqlite

Tags: java, android, json

I am completely stuck on this and need help.

I need to get the value if another value is equal to something.

Lets say my array is:

```
"people":[
    {"name": "David", "age": "30"}, 
    {"name": "Bob", "age": "20"}, 
    {"name": "Bill", "age": "30"}
]
```

I need to return the age if the name is lets say Bob. I have attempted to do it this way but to no avail.

```
String People = jsonPart.getString("people");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(People);

for (int h = 0; h < arr.length(); h++) {

    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(h);

    String name = jsonPart.getString("name");

    if (name == "Bob") {

        String age = jsonPart.getString("age");

        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot do String comparisons in Java using the `==` operator. You must use `String#equals` so replace this line:

`if (name == "Bob") {`

with

`if(name.equals("Bob")) {`

See this link for more info:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-compare-strings
and
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html

Comment: Now I feel very silly what worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidG you should accept the question as it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
If("Bob".equals(name))
```

to avoid NullPointerException if the name is null.